# .htaccess mod_rewrite 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My url is now `mysite.com/steam/g?appid=730`

What I want is:  `mysite.com/steam/directory/730`

Here is what I have so far:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*)$ /steam/g.php?appid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now this will only give me a 404 not found. I believe mod_rewrite is enabled as I can rewrite everything to https and remove the .php .html etc. I'm using a web host.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
RewriteRule ^steam/directory/(.*)$ /steam/g.php?appid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your original URL was: `http://example.com/steam/g.php?appid=730`
I think the following should get you the format you want.

```
RewriteRule ^steam/directory/([^/]*)$ /steam/g.php?appid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I wish I could mark the both of you as correct answer. Atleast I can give you an upvote :)